# Name of a specialized A-to-mini-B USB cable

Tags: usb

I am looking for a USB cable with the following properties:

- Mini-B connector on one end, A connector on the other end
- Pins 4 and 5 on the mini-B connector end shorted
- Injection mold casing on both ends to protect the soldering connections

What is this type of USB cable called?

Comment: What sort of connector on the other end?

Comment: A. But on the mini-B end, pins 4 and 5 are shorted.